# C++ - Strand sort using arrays only

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I got a homework, to create a `Strand sort` algorithm in C++, but I'm not allowed to use `lists`, only `arrays`. I have trouble understanding the algorithm, because it was never explained to me, and Google yields limited information on this subject.

I've tried my best porting the code I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strand_sort#Algorithm), from PHP to C++, but It's not working correctly. **It doesn't sort the array.**

Here is my code, I know a lot of it is probably badly written, but it's the best I could do with my knowledge.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void echoArray(int a[], int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

//removes an element from array
int* array_remove(int* a, int& n, int index) {
    int p = 0;
    int* newArray = new int[n - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(i != index) {
            newArray[p] = a[i];
            p++;
        }
    }
    n--;
    return newArray;
}
//adds an element to the end of an array
int* array_append(int* a, int& n, int el) {
    int* newArray = new int[n+1];
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < n; i++) {
        newArray[i] = a[i];
    }
    if(n == 0)
        i = 0;
    newArray[i] = el;
    n++;
    return newArray;
}

//inserts an element (el) to index p
int* array_insert(int* a, int& n, int p, int el) {
    int c = 0;
    n++;
    int* newArray = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(i != p) {
            newArray[i] = a[c];
            c++;
        } else {
            newArray[i] = el;
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

int* strandSort(int* a, int n) {
    int arrC = n;
    int resC = 0;
    int subC = 0;
    int* result = new int[1];
    while(arrC > 0) {
        subC = 0;
        int* sublist = new int[1];
        sublist = array_append(sublist, subC, a[0]);
        a = array_remove(a, arrC, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < arrC; i++) {
            if(a[i] > sublist[subC - 1]) {
                sublist = array_append(sublist, subC, a[i]);
                a = array_remove(a, arrC, i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        if(resC > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < subC; i++) {
                bool spliced = false;
                for(int j = 0; j < resC - 1; i++) {
                    if(sublist[i] > result[j]) {
                        result = array_insert(result, resC, i, sublist[i]);
                        spliced = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!spliced) {
                    result = array_append(result, resC, sublist[i]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            result = sublist;
            resC = subC;
        }
    }
    echoArray(result, resC);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {3, 20, 6, 1, 19, 21, 6, 11, 25, 6, 0, 1, 8, 7, 29, 26, 10, 29, 9, 5};
    int n = 20;
    strandSort(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I realize that arrays are passed by reference.

Comment: hope this will help you http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/Software.coe/242-535_ADA/Background/Readings/Robert%20Sedgewick%20and%20Kevin%20Wayne%20-%20Algorithms,%204th%20edition.pdf

Comment: @barakmanos, this is not the complete program. I know I've made some basic mistakes, and I know that arrays are passed by reference, but that is not the point of my question. I'm using a return value, because the assignment requires me to do so. Since the function wasn't working initially, I didn't bother returning the sorted array, but just printed out the array, to see what the result is.

Comment: Define "not working". Compile error (if so, include the exact message)? Runtime error? Not sorting correctly (if so, include example input and expected and actual output)?

Comment: @Dukeling It doesn't sort the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `cout<<` to target the problem

After read the wiki of `Strand Sort`, we know there is two parts of this algorithm.

1. Take out a relatively sorted list
2. Merge it with the result list

So you need to find which part is wrong, just add

```
    cout << "step1: sublist = ";
    echoArray(sublist, subC);
```

before `if(resC > 0) {` we will see step1 is right or wrong.

Add

```
    cout << "step2: result = ";
    echoArray(result, resC);
```

In the bottom of the `while(arrC > 0) {}` loop to check step2.

Get:

```
step1: sublist = 3 20 21 25 29 
step2: result = 3 20 21 25 29 
step1: sublist = 6 19 26 29 
step2: result = 6 19 26 29 3 20 21 25 29 
step1: sublist = 1 6 11 
step2: result = 6 19 11 26 29 3 20 21 25 29 
step1: sublist = 6 8 10 
step2: result = 6 8 10 19 11 26 29 3 20 21 25 29 
step1: sublist = 0 1 7 9 
step2: result = 6 8 7 9 10 19 11 26 29 3 20 21 25 29 
step1: sublist = 5 
step2: result = 6 8 7 9 10 19 11 26 29 3 20 21 25 29 0
```

As we can see step1 is always right but the merge step is wrong.

So we will focus the code in `if(resC > 0) {}` block.

### Read the code carefully

If you read your code carefully you will find in `for(int j = 0; j < resC - 1; i++) {` the `i++` is nonsense.

And the merge step has many bugs, you need to rethink about it.

### The fixed code of step 2:

```
if(resC > 0) {
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < subC; i++) {
        bool spliced = false;
        for(;j < resC; j++) {
            if(sublist[i] < result[j]) {
                result = array_insert(result, resC, j++, sublist[i]);
                spliced = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!spliced) {
            result = array_append(result, resC, sublist[i]);
        }
    }
} else {
    result = sublist;
    resC = subC;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now, that I've made some dumb mistakes.